# Symfony Elastic Update

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "~3.0" "ruflin/elastica": "~2.1,<2.3", and php 5.5.9 and we update elasticsearch from 1.7.3 to 2.0 and when I try update or create index like fos:elastica:populate I have error

```
Error: Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]]) {"type":1,"file":"/home/ivan/host/aog-code /vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Exception/ResponseException.php"
......
Error: Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]])
```

I try find how to solved this problem, after update, and could not find. I try update FOSElasticaBundle
to dev-master / 3.2.x-dev but still have problem. Now there is a solution for elasticsearch 2.0?

Answer (score 3):

I find out the solution, described here.

In your composer.json file add :

```
"friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "dev-master",
"ruflin/elastica": "3.1.1 as 2.99.0"
```

Comment: i can verify adding this to the main composer.json file works.  I now get an error message i can work with :-)